# Routing Roles upon login MVC5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, roles

I am very new to MVC and I am currently creating a web application which requires routed login. I have 3 Users - Admin, Optician and User. Upon Login I wish for the Admin to be redirected to the Admin page, the Optician to be redirected to the Opticians page and the User to be redirected to the Home page. 
Upon Start up I have created the roles. I have registered the users to the roles and that is working correctly. What I am trying to do now is route the roles upon login.

Start Up Auth:

```
        // Creating new instance of Role Manager
        var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        //Creating User role
        RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("User"));
        //Creating Admin role
        RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
        //Creating Optician role
        RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Optician"));
```

Account Controller:

```
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                if(User.IsInRole("Admin")){
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else if (User.IsInRole("Optician"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Optician");
                }
                else
                {   // if role is User
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Route Config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

However when logged in as an Admin or Optician I am  redirected to - RedirectToLocal(returnUrl) and not the ("Index", "Admin") or ("Index", "Optician"). Apologies in advance for the simplicity of this question but I am unsure of where I am going wrong.Should the if statement be in the POST login? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code? Is the `User.IsInRole("Admin")` returning true? Is `RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin")` being called?

Comment: @NightOwl888 User.IsInRole("Admin") is true however it does not route to ("Index", "Admin") it goes to RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)

Comment: can you provide your routeconfig?

Comment: @hjgraca I've added in the route config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out where I was going wrong. I needed to create a redirect method as the user is not yet signed in with their role at the Login stage. Upon Login in the user is then directed to the redirect method which redirects them according to their role.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }


        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("RedirectLogin"); 
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectLogin(string returnUrl)
    {
        if(User.IsInRole("Admin")){
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else if (User.IsInRole("Optician"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Optician");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
    }
```

Comment: *Comment from [Luis Ruiz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5275342/luis-ruiz):* The only thing you are missing in that code is `case SignInStatus.Success: return RedirectToAction("RedirectLogin", new {ReturnUrl = returUrl);` so you can return to the proper URL if he is signing in as something else.